# What to do when I don't understand an answer and author don't reply?

Tags: discussion, support

What to do when I don't understand an answer and author don't reply?

[Solve for x $ \sin 30° \sin x \sin 10° = \sin 20° \sin ({80°-x}) \sin 40° $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225027/solve-for-x-sin-30-sin-x-sin-10-sin-20-sin-80-x-sin-40/3257288?noredirect=1#comment6702291_3257288)

So someone answered my question and I don't understand a part of it. I asked the author and I did get a reply but it's not helpful enough. What to do in such cases? 
Should I ask a separate question on the main site regarding it?

Comment: Related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16502/how-best-to-re-ask-a-question-that-wasnt-fully-answered

Comment: Also this is related: [Clarify an old answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4108).

Comment: And maybe also asking in some of [various chatrooms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/list-of-chatrooms) associated with this site might be worth trying.